# Nuxt: How to know that hydration has been finished?

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

**Situation**

I save tour pages that user has visited in order to show "Recently visited tours" on the home page when user comes back to the site. Visited tours I save with [vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate).

The code is simple: `<TheVisitedTours v-show=toursRecentlyViewed.length" />`

**Problem**

When user comes back, there are the next hydration issues:

```
Parent:  <div style=​"display:​none;​" data-v-24f9a6f4>​…​</div>​ 

Mismatching childNodes vs. VNodes:  NodeList(3) [comment, text, comment] (5) [VNode, VNode, VNode, VNode, VNode]
 
[Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.
```

It is obvious that SSR does not have info about Visited tours and vuex-persistedstate restores info about visited tours before hydration is finished.

In case if I use v-show instead of v-if I see:

`[Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.`

I have tried to wrap it into `<client-only>...</client-only>` but it does not help.

Also I have tried to use:

```
mounted () {
  this.isMounted = true
}
```

and

```
mounted () {
  window.onNuxtReady(() => {
    this.isMounted = true
  })
}
```

with

`<TheVisitedTours v-if=isMounted && toursRecentlyViewed.length" />`

but it also does not work.

**Question**

Is there any event I can listen for to know that hydration has been finished? If no, maybe someone have any workaround ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution.

My initial code used [vue-lazy-hydration](https://github.com/maoberlehner/vue-lazy-hydration)

```
<LazyHydrate when-visible>
  <b-container>

    ......
  
    <client-only>
      <TheVisitedTours v-show=toursRecentlyViewed.length" />
    </client-only>
  </b-container>
</LazyHydrate>
```

Once `LazyHydrate` removed, `<client-only>` fixed an issue.

Comment: were you able to find a solution without removing `<Lazyhydrate>` ?

Comment: @PavelGurecki no